# Android: Parse json using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am using httpurlconnection and I can't find understandeble way to parse my json. 
attribute output return this json {"value":"SUCCESS"}
but how to parse the json?

code

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


    String ue=params[1];

    try {

        //final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
        URL url = new URL("my url return json ");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        String urlParameters = "e="+ue;
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        dStream.flush();
        dStream.close();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("output===============" + br);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            responseOutput.append(line);
        }
        br.close();

        output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());

        register.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //output;
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output.toString());
                        message = json.optString("value");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               Toast.makeText(register.this,"output: "+output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

if there is any dependences that I should to add to gradel.Please, let me know! thank you in advance

Comment: There are libraries that exist that make all the code you have for HTTP calls unnecessary. Two examples are OkHttp or Volley. If you are working just with JSON, then Retrofit is another.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output); // output string
        String message = json.optString("value"); // SUCCESS
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I would recommend to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: display error because the output type is StringBuilder. yes please do you have any good tutorial to use Gson library because I am new in java

Comment: use it like this: `new JSONObject(output.toString());`

Comment: I try it and it's return null, while before I use JSONObject is return {"value":"SUCCESS"}  !

Comment: pass this **string** `{"value":"SUCCESS"}` as parameter to the constructor `new JSONObject("_here_");`. you are doing it wrong otherwise. Post it how are you using it.

Comment: yes I post how I used new JSONObject(output.tostring());

Comment: can you check the value of `output.toString()` before passing it to JSONObject?

Comment: return {"value":"SUCCESS"}. so why after pass it to JSONObject return null?

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, but return null result . Is the line of the code is effect?(                 output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());
) ?

Comment: yes it does. I told you to print it before setting it to `JSONObject`. Anyway, try it now.

Comment: Whatever is the output, just pass it directly to JSONObject, without appending anything to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108047/discussion-between-rohit-arya-and-seham).